# Can Amazon Chime be deployed and run on a third-party VPS? And how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

In the examples of Amazon Chime, for instance here https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk-classroom-demo, they imply that it should be deployed and run on a AWS server via Cloud9. However, I want to deploy and run it on some other VPS such as a digitalocean or linode server.

The main question: can that be done at all, it is supported?

If yes, how? General pointers. Which example should I use and where is it described at all?

Eventually what I want is this:

Say, I have a teaching website that I run on digital ocean or linode. Not on AWS. I want to be able to use Amazon Chime in a way that my users will go to **my website** and connect to a video class from   **my website as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chime service would need run on AWS, but you can have a link to the Chime service endpoint from any website hosted anywhere else.

To use the Amazon Chime web application, your students would sign in to https://app.chime.aws/ from your web browser. You would have that link on your website.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/ug/chime-web-app.html

Note about the demo. The demo shows how to use the Amazon Chime SDK to build an online classroom in Electron and React. If you are are using that deployment method you can host the React app anywhere under a private domain on any host. That app will run any where, while connecting back to the AWS service endpoint.

Comment: `The Chime service would need run on AWS, but you can have a link to the Chime service endpoint from any website hosted anywhere else.` --> where will a user have to connect to a class -- via my website and remaing on my website too or will he have to go or be redirected at AWS?

Comment: If you deploy the demo app in your website, then they would remain on the website. But you need to manage the react app as part of your website.

Answer (score 1):

Resources would be deployed in AWS. No way around it.

Deployment script can be run from your own laptop, Cloud9 and/or any other Linux server. You just need to be able to run `git clone` and `script/deploy.js`.

You'll also need to make that environment is configured with appropriate AWS credentials. Cloud9 would have these credentials out of the box. For any other environment (your laptop/Digital Ocean VM etc.) would need to get AWS Account Ket/Secret pair and use `aws config` to enable them.

Comment: 1) what resources?

Comment: also 2) Say, I have a teaching website that I run on digital ocean or linode. Can I use Amazon Chime in a way that my users will go to *my website* and connect to a video class from there  as well?

Comment: The code in the repo builds and deploys react/electron app, few lambda functions, S3 buckets...